# What impact would it have if all posts were Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Hypothetically speaking, what impact on the site would it have if all posts were [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/169404)?

I like how the site works now because I take ownership in my questions and answers, but I was wondering if the site would be radically different. If there was a good way to moderate it, would it lead to higher quality answers that stay up to date?

Comment: It would make asking bad questions and giving bad answers something that has no consequence (reputation wise), meaning crap would accumulate faster than it could get rid of.

Comment: @Oded That makes sense. But I think the nature of voting to delete/close would be different.

Comment: Possibly. But this is naval gazing. We don't really know. The system is very complex and even little changes have very big impact. The only way to find out is to change the system in this way - I don't think anyone really wants to experiment in such a manner...

Comment: Even for meta, a purely hypothetical "what if" type question like this is a bit much. :)

Comment: As well as the above, if all posts were Community Wiki then in it's current incarnation reputation would become obsolete.  Whilst you could debate whether this is a good or a bad thing, it *would* lead to the collapse of the reputation linked privileges system as it currently stands, including most measures for peer review, quality control and moderation.

Comment: Hmmm, this seems like a good topic of discussion, i.e. NOT `not constructive`.  Though I do hope it gets downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: Of course Austin might want to delete it himself and see if there is a secret hat for deleting your own negative post.  Testing right now on another post.

Comment: Nope, no hat for deleting your own negative post (maybe if you get the PP badge, but you can only get that once).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really sure where you're going with this discussion but it's like asking "what impact on the world would it have if there will be no money any more"?

Stack Exchange is based on reputation, this is the oil in its gears. For good or for bad, this is how the system was designed: post good contents and earn points; post bad contents and you would lose points. Clean and simple, and looks like it's working really well.

So, back to the question: if you ask me, without ordinary posts and/or without reputation Stack Overflow (and probably any other Stack Exchange site) will cease to exist, most likely faster than the speed of light. :)

Comment: We could have ["coupins."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClQuI8ds_dg)